# How to passing parameter from json-rpc to the API function in zabbix?

Tags: php, zabbix

I am writing API for zabbix monitoring as below.

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "data.delete",
    "params":{
            "startTimestamp": "1560725284",
            "endTimestamp": "1560725644",
            "deleteType": "0"
        },
    "auth": "6a810d97a79ef6d31ddde7bf93103299",
    "id": 1
}
```

I create CData.php api service and wrote the function delete() as below:

```
    public function delete($startTimestamp, $endTimestamp, $deleteType) {

        $from = zbx_toArray($startTimestamp);

        $to = zbx_toArray($endTimestamp);

        $type = zbx_toArray($deleteType);

        // delete action conditions
        $sql = 'delete from history where clock >='.$from.' and clock <= '.$to;
        DBexecute($sql);

        return ['success' => '200', 'message' => 'Đã xóa thành công', 'startTimestamp' => $from, 'endTimestamp' => $to, 'deleteType' =>$type];
    }
```

When I call the API as get method have problem:
 CLocalApiClient.php line 123
$result = call_user_func_array([$this->serviceFactory->getObject($api), $method], [$params]);

and function CLocalApiClient->callMethod( ???, ???, ???, ??? )

The CData service error on CData->delete( ???, ???, ??? )

When I tried some code as below, it worked fine.

```
    public function delete() {

        $from = "1563229215";
        $to = "1563229275";
        $type = "0";

        // delete action conditions
        $sql = 'delete from history where clock >='.$from.' and clock <= '.$to;
        DBexecute($sql);

        return ['success' => '200', 'message' => 'Đã xóa thành công', 'startTimestamp' => $from, 'endTimestamp' => $to, 'deleteType' =>$type];
    }
```

Please help me how to passing the params into api function?

Thank you so much,
BienHV

Answer (score 0):

I was found the solution for this question. I change the delete function as below.

```
public function delete(array $data) {

    $from = $data['startTimestamp'];

    $to = $data['endTimestamp'];

    $type = $data['deleteType'];

    // delete action conditions
    $deleteHistory = 'delete from history where clock >='.$from.' and clock <= '.$to;

    if (!DBexecute($deleteHistory)) {
        self::exception(ZBX_API_ERROR_PARAMETERS, 'Cannot delete history');
    }

    return ['success' => '200', 'message' => 'Delete success', 'startTimestamp' => $startTimestamp, 'endTimestamp' => $to, 'deleteType' =>$type];
}
```